# What's the meaning of the "en" in the sentence?

Tags: sens, pronoms

Je voudrais des explications sur le mot *en* dans la phrase suivante,

> Il se faisait régulièrement les cheveux et portait des vêtements qui, pour être vieux et usés, n'**en** étaient pas moins propres.

Merci de votre aide.

Answer (score 1):

*En* se réfère à la situation décrite, ici des vêtements qui, nous dit-on, sont vieux et usés. Si ces vêtements sont vieux et usés, on pourrait légitimement s'attendre à ce qu'ils soient également sales. L'expression *n'en était pas moins* exprime le fait que malgré ce que l'on pourrait attendre/s'imaginer, la réalité est différente.

Il existe d'autres expressions du même genre comme :

> Il n'en est pas moins...
>
> Il n'en reste pas moins que...

Et d'autres expressions où *en* se réfère à une situation décrite (précédemment ou juste après), comme :

> À l'en croire [...] *(si l'on croit ce qu'il dit)*
>
> Je m'en fiche ! *(Je me fiche de ce qui a été dit/décrit)*
>
> J'en ai profité pour [...] *(J'ai profité de cette situation pour [...])*